# how to process single flowfile at a time in nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

NiFi version 1.5(3 node cluster).

i am having nifi flow as 
ListFTP -> FetchFTP(1) -> RouteOnAttribute -> .... -> UpdateAttribute -> **FetchFTP(2)** -> ExecuteGroovyScript -> PutFTP

everything works fine. when the flowfile comes to FetchFTP(2), **i want to process single flowfile at a time with interval of 30 sec.** **irrespective of 3 nodes parallel processing of flowfile.**

things i tried:

1. Setting RunSchedule to 30sec.

   PROBLEM: it did not worked because each flowfile has been processed initially by different nodes. when it comes to FetchFTP, three flowfiles are processed at the same time.
   Also tried Execution mode to "Primary" from "All nodes". This did not worked since FetchFTP processing only the flowfile which was initially processed by primary node, all other flowfile(processed by different node) stays in queue.
2. using ControlRate before the FetchFTP processor.
   three flowfiles are getting processed simultaneously.
3. using Wait and Notify processor.
   three flowfiles are getting processed simultaneously.

is something i am missing out or any other better way of doing.

Comment: seems 2 works for you (except all 3 nodes executed). just apply "execute on primary node" for all 3 processors listftp, controlrate, fetchftp

Comment: i want second FetchFTP before ExecuteGroovyScript to process single flowfile. when the flowfile comes to FetchFTP, all the flowfiles are having different node address. Also, i want all the nodes to process the flowfiles and then later in second FetchFTP to process single flowfile irrespective of node address.

Answer (score 2):

Use some simple processor between ListFtp and FetchFtp. For example UpdateAttribute (Barrier on image below)

Set load balancing on queue between Barrier and FetchFtp to balance files between nodes.

And set for the Barrier `schedule=30 sec` and run on primary node only.

Alternatively, you could play with back pressure for queues.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But i am getting ListFTP(primary) -> FetchFTP(primary) -> after this i am having around 15 processors for manipulation which has different node address -> then finally i am using FetchFTP, here it does not process single flowfile even when i use schedule=30 sec or backpressure=1 since it is working in cluster mode.

Comment: I suggested to use primary node on processor before fetchftp and limit throughput by one file per 30sec.

Comment: since different flowfile has different node address assigned. the processor before FetchFTP does not getting processed for other node address if we use Primary option.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to process single flowfile at a time with interval of 30 sec.
>   irrespective of 3 nodes parallel processing of flowfile.

There's an option in each processor's configuration panel to execute on the primary node only when doing clustered mode. I don't necessarily recommend it for performance reasons, but if you're confident you need it here, it should do the trick to ensure "1 thread, 1 process only" across the cluster.

Comment: thanks. though receiving original file using primary only option, after that using many other processors for manipulating flowfiles, hence different flowfiles has different node address assigned to it. finally when i use FetchFTP with schedule or backpressure set, it is working in cluster mode only.